# Matching attributes to needs in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a problem which essentially breaks down to scheduling meeting rooms and I'm trying to find the best way to sensibly store and retrieve this data in SQL.

For example:

```
possible_features = beer_fridge, vga_projector, hdmi_projector, doughnut_machine, conference_phone

meeting_rooms = {
                  room_a: (beer_fridge,hdmi_projector),
                  room_b: (beer_fridge,vga_projector,conference_phone),
                  room_c: (vga_projector,hdmi_projector,conference_phone,doughnut_machine),
                }

meetings = {
             morning: (hdmi_projector),
             devs: (beer_fridge,hdmi_projector),
             evening: (conference_phone,vga_projector),
           }
```

The kinds of questions I need to ask are:

- which rooms are suitable for the morning meeting?
- which rooms have a conference_phone?

What's a sensible way to represent this data in the database (the list of fixtures is *not* known up front) and do queries against it?

What's the name of this pattern? I'm sure I'm not the first one to have this problem.

*(if answers are DBMS-specific, we'll be using MySQL)*

Answer (score 2):

I see five tables:

- feature (*id_feature*, name, ...)
- room (*id_room*, roomnumber, ...)
- room_feature (*id_room*, *id_feature*)
- meeting (*id_meeting*, info, ...)
- meeting_feature (*id_meeting*, *id_feature*)

This is nothing specific. It's a normalized database, nothing more.

The query to get the rooms for the meeting would be: Get all rooms for which no meeting features exists that don't exists in that room.

```
select r.*
from room r
where not exists
(
  select * 
  from meating_feature mf 
  where mf.id_meeting = 1
  and not exists
  (
    select *
    from room_feature rf 
    where rf.id_feature = mf.id_feature and rf.id_room = r.id_room
  )
);
```

Most dbms, however don't support that depth. r.id_room is no longer known in the second NOT EXISTS subquery. So one has to write the query a bit differently:

```
select r.*
from room r
where not exists
(
  select * 
  from meating_feature mf 
  left join room_feature rf on mf.id_feature = rf.id_feature and rf.id_room = r.id_room
  where mf.id_meeting = 1
  and rf.id_feature is null
);
```

(There are other ways to solve this, too. You could select room feateres that are needed for a meating and then compare each room's number of found features with the number of needed features, for instance.)

The query to get rooms with a conference phone is easier:

```
select *
from room
where id_room in
(
  select id_room
  from room_feature
  where id_feature = (select id_feature from feature where name = 'conference phone')
);
```